# How to output string as HTML when using html encode in view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how to get html markup language to be displayed in a web page when using `Html Encode` which is being used to replace some string like in the example below.

```
@(Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Test).Replace("\n", "<br />")))
```

Of course, just using

`@(Html.Raw(Model.Name)) e.g.<b>test/b>` = **test**

Will achieve what I am asking for but then I will lose the replace code.

I could do this replacing functionality in the controller which may be the best method. However, I am intrigued to whether this can be done just in the view.

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to replace any "\n" entries with "<br />"? If so, you shouldn't need to encode....

Comment: Interesting, I will state that isnt the code i wrote, i have picked the code up, so therefore its a working piece of code, so I dont want to change it if necessary and just append it to write Raw html. How else can I replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
@Html.Raw("<b>test</b>")
```

for this.

```
Html.Encode(Model.Test)
```

actually changes the string  <b> to

```
&lt;b&gt;
```

so in fact I think this should be enough

```
@(Html.Raw(Model.Test.Replace("\n", "<br />")))
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see why this would work and of course complies correctly, I will test and then mark as correct, but thanks, a pretty simple solution